# What are the must know topics for personal accounting?

Tags: accounting, bookkeeping, cash-flow, learning

I'm 18 years old; last year I finished high school. I attended a school oriented in accounting, and even though I didn't care much about it at the time, now I realize how important is to know how to manage money in my everyday life.

So my question is: What are the main concepts I must know to have a solid understanding about personal accounting? I'm looking for some sort of study plan.

Although I learned a lot in high school, there are things I didn't pay much attention to and I don't remember now. Also, I want to make sure there aren't any topics that I may have missed at school.

Thanks in advance for all your responses and suggestions!!

Comment: Just FYI, there was a 3-2 vote split for the *reason* this question was put on hold. The majority was "off-topic", but the minority, which I feel is the far better reason, was "too broad". I feel this question would be on topic, but unfortunately the best answer is pretty much something akin to: "Pick any topic you want to learn about and read the questions and answers about it on this site."

Comment: Paula, please don't be discouraged by the fact that this question was put on hold. That you asked this at your age is very promising! My suggestion to you is to start browsing the site and learning what you can, and when more specific questions come up, feel free to fire away. Good luck!

Comment: @TTT It's true the question is solely about accounting, i didn't realized it could be off topic. And yes, it could be a broad question but i was just asking for a list of topics, not an explanation of each one. Anyway, thanks for you comments, i'll keep searching elsewere ;)

Answer (score 2):

This may seem overly simple, but the most important thing to know is "live beneath your means".

If your income is, for example, $2000 per month, spending $2001 or more per month is a sure path to ruin. Spending $1999 or less is the secret to success.

Everything else on this forum is mere commentary on the above.